# How to bind json data

Tags: php, jquery, json

I've json response from server looks like that

```
{  
  "117":{  
     "09:00":5,
     "10:00":5,
     "11:00":5,
     "12:00":5,
     "13:00":5,
     "14:00":5,
     "15:00":5,
     "16:00":5,
     "17:00":5,
     "18:00":5,
     "19:00":5
  }
}
```

How I can bind this to normal select to looks like that

```
<select name="time" id="time">
   <option value="5">09:00</option>
   <option value="5">10:00</option>
  <option value="5">11:00</option>
</select>
```

Hours are not always the same, could be from 11:00 to 21:00. 
Any idea how to display this in php or bind by jquery.
Thank you for response

Comment: what have you *tried yourself* so far?

Comment: show us your Code

Comment: Also, what's the point in lots of different select options if they're all the same value...

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop:

```js
var objString = '{"117": {"09:00": 5,"10:00": 5,"11:00": 5,"12:00": 5,"13:00": 5,"14:00": 5,"15:00": 5,"16:00": 5,"17:00": 5,"18:00": 5,"19:00": 5}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(objString);
$.each(obj["117"], function(i, v) {
  $('#time').append('<option value="' + v + '">' + i + '</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="time"></select>
```

Comment: I've always the same error. By the way 117 could be a different numer  
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Comment: parse your string to json